# How do I get the dynamic play/pause functionality working in Video.js?

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I have a html5 video player and by default it does not allow you to click on the `<video></video>` player and it will not pause/play.

How do i get the HTML5 Video.js Play/Pause functionality to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery

`$('#your_element_id')[0].pause()` to pause 
`$('#your_element_id')[0].play()` to play

Javascript

`document.getElementById("your_element_id").pause()` to pause
`document.getElementById("your_element_id").play()` to play

Comment: Tried to do this and in return on chrome I got this. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of undefined

Comment: you are supposed to replace `your_element_id` with the id you gave to your `<video>` element

Comment: my code `<script type="text/javascript">
$('#vine')[0].pause(), $('#vine')[0].play()
</script>` and my video tag `<video id="vine"` cutt off but it's set.

Comment: You have loaded jQuery right?

Comment: Yeah, my current..

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: the comma in my answer originally was not part of the code, it was seperating the code to pause the video from the code to play the video

Comment: I appreciate your patients. Was solved using this `http://jsfiddle.net/yPn4J/4/` but I have no doubt your method also works. Thank's for the help!